# ¿Como obtener valores de un modelo en flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Estoy tratando de obtener los valores de un modelo en flask, quiero acceder a los valores de mi modelo, no un "`render_template`"

`record = MyModel.query.filter_by(id=222)`

Pero con esto me regresa un consulta de SQL.

La idea es acceder como si fuera un diccionario y obtener los valores con `get()`

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Debieras poder transformar el record en diccionario con `dict(record.__dict__)`

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado

Comment: ¿Qué ORM estás usando?

Comment: @César sqlalchemy

Answer (score 1):

Si no me equivoco, `filter_by` te retorna un objeto que puedes iterar, sin embargo, veo que lo que realmente quieres es un registro específico por lo que lo mejor que puedes hacer es usar `get`:

```
record = MyModel.query.get(id=222)
```

Luego puedes acceder a los campos que has definido en tu modelo:

```
record.campoX
record.campoY
# ...
```

Por otro lado, si tu query lo usas para filtrar varios registros entonces puedes hacer:

```
records = MyModel.query.filter_by(...)
for record in records:
    record.campoX
    record.campoY
    # ...
```

No veo razón alguna para querer acceder a los campos usando diccionarios pero, de hecho, podrías hacerlo usando `__dict__` (como menciona @amenadiel):

```
record.__dict__.get('campoX')
```

Más código y menos sentido.

Comment: Al final no accedi con diccionarios, lo use para filtrar los datos ```record = MyModel.query.filter_by(id=222).first()```